# Do I need to update log4j.properties file if I use the Log4j 1.x bridge (log4j-1.2-api)

Tags: log4j

I've followed the doc here : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html
Also looked at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties

My existing log4j.properties only uses DailyRollingFileAppender, ConsoleAppender, both of which are under the 'Supported Components', so I shouldn't be forced to convert my log4j.properties file  into log4j2.properties format. I'm not accessing methods and classes internal to the Log4j 1.x implementation, as suggested by the document.

For using the bridge, I previously was using both log4j1.compatibility and log4j.configuration, but the document suggests using 'any one' (tried using just one, doesn't work)

I can build my application successfully, however, my application no longer logs anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out.
The answer lied in the Automatic Configuration section

Comment: So WHAT WAS THE ANSWER?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [reload4j](https://reload4j.qos.ch) as a drop-in replacement for log4j 1.x. Initiated by Ceki Gülcü, the original author of Apache log4j 1.x, the reload4j project is a fork of Apache log4j version 1.2.17 with the goal of fixing pressing security issues.

The reload4j project offers a clear and easy migration path for the users who have an urgent need to fix vulnerabilities in log4j 1.2.17.

Comment: Thanks for responding Ceki, I really appreciate it :)
What I noticed from this doc https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration was that my console logging was happening (#10), which meant I had to trigger #1 or #6 (since I use a .properties file)
After I got that figured, I had to create a new log4j2.properties file, and use the log4j2 properties syntax to get this working.
It's definitely been a good learning experience.
PS : Damn, that's your own lib! Good job! I'll go over it.
PPS : You are the author of log4j 1.x ! OMG!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update your properties file.

You can add a `log4j2.component.properties` file on the class path (in my case, in the same directory as my log4j.properties file) to set the log4j1.compatibility property, like this:

`log4j1.compatibility=true`

In our case, it only required setting the compatibility property and then it automatically picked up the log4j.properties file that was available on the class path.